# How to retrieve value from key:function the same way as key:value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, function, object-literal

How can I retrieve foo2.x the same way as I retrieve foo1.x?

```
var foo1 = {x: 4};
var foo2 = {x: function(){return addOne(foo1.x);}}

function addOne(var1){return (var1 + 1);}

alert(foo1.x);
alert(foo2.x()); // needs parentheses, but argument is never needed
```

Comment: The value *is* the function, so what do you want?

Comment: Answer: Don't do that.  You should fix your objects so that they're consistent.

Comment: I need a way to handle them in a similar way. Say I want to draw a line, then I need something like lineFunc(foo1.x, foo2.x()). I don't want the program to check if it needs to use () or not.

Comment: @wubbewubbewubbe: Then why don't you just set `foo2.x` to `5`? What are you trying to do with that, what are those objects made for? Some context please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want to store the *result* of that function in `foo2.x`, not the function itself.

Try the following:

```
function addOne(n) {
    return n + 1;
}

var
foo1 = {
    x: 4
},
foo2 = {
    x: (function () {
        return addOne(foo1.x);
    }())
};

alert(foo1.x); // 4
alert(foo2.x); // 5
```

I've wrapped the function in `foo2.x` with parentheses, and put an extra pair of parens after it to execute it. So it's no longer a function, but the result of the function.

Comment: Why not just `foo2 = {x: addOne(foo1.x)}`? The IEFE is so useless.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want a [getter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters):

```
var foo1 = {x: 4},
    foo2 = {get x() { return foo1.x + 1; }};

foo2.x; // 5
foo1.x = 0;
foo2.x; // 1
```

Comment: thank you, this comment proved to be more useful than I thought it would be when I first looked at it

Comment: yep, done. I used Object.defineProperty to attach it at a later time and it seems to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`foo2.x` is a function, so you need to add parenthesis